# Range.Formula error with user defined functions

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hello guy I have a user defined function inside VBA

```
Function clean(word As String, ParamArray characters() As Variant) As String
        For i = 0 To UBound(characters)
            word = Replace(word, characters(i), "")
        Next i
    clean = word
End Function
```

whenever I try to use it in another subroutine like that

```
Sub prova()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsB As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsB = wb.Sheets("Bond Holdings")
    wsB.Range("R3").Formula = "=clean(""dfsduuu"",""u"")"
End Sub
```

I get runtime error 1004. Could you guys help me figure out why? this is driving me crazy.

Thank you

Comment: `Clean` is already a function in Excel.  Try renaming it to `Clean2` or something or other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has a built-in function called `CLEAN`. You have a name-clash. If you call your function e.g. `cleaner`, it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you ... it worked like a charm